# iTunes Connect: App name with special character "✡"

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I want to add the special character "✡" to app name in iTunes Connect, but iTunes Connect sounds it's not allowed, and then I've tried this: "&#11017" , but it shows up in plain text in summary view. And "&#11017" is displayed with "✡" in app description properly. What can I do?

Comment: Are you sure you _need_ to have this symbol?  What about omitting it for submission and then putting it in the CFBundleDisplayName (which accepts Unicode).

Comment: Thanks for your comments. CFBundleDisplayName is the name showing in iphone, it's not be display name in app store. I want to display the app name with "✡" in app store.

Comment: As you have seen, ITC lacks a clear support for unicode chars.  You may be stuck, unless there is some way to represent the symbols... Possibly in Yiddish or Hebrew?   Even among accepted apps, the Star of David symbol doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: I tried to use the unicode "&#11017" to instead of "✡", The app name also is one html entity in the ITC page, why it is just shows in plain text?